# How to check if file exists in in set of paths?

Tags: php

How to check if file is in in the selected path?

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] === '/home/user/soloj';
```

Several paths:

```
/home/user/soloj/admin/user/file.php // false
/home/user/soloj/client/file.php // false
/home/user/soloj/public/file.php // true
/home/user/soloj/temp/file.php // true
/home/user/soloj/temp/folder/folder/file.php // true - all after temp is true
/home/user/soloj/zero/file.php // false
```

So if file is in `/home/user/soloj/public/` or `/home/user/soloj/temp/*` then my function should return true;

```
$paths = array(
    '/home/user/soloj/public/',
    '/home/user/soloj/temp'
);

function check($paths, $path)
{
   if ($path IN $paths) {
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}

check($paths, 'public/file.php'); // true
check($paths, 'zero/file.php'); // false
check($paths, 'temp/aaa/file.php'); // true
check($paths, 'public/../zero/file.php'); // false
```

Comment: It can probably be done using [`DirectoryIterator::getFileName`](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getfilename.php) possibly with [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Perhaps [try it yourself](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) (link hint), before posting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
function check($paths, $filepath)
{
     $filepath = ltrim($filepath, '/'); //remove leading slashes
     foreach($paths as $path){
         $path = rtrim($path, '/').'/';  //insure consistent tailing slashes
         if(file_exists($path.$filepath)) return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Because you have mismatched `/`

```
$paths = array(
  '/home/user/soloj/public/',
  '/home/user/soloj/temp'
);
```

I added some stuff to clean that up. I also cleaned up the variable names a bit.

Without normalizing that you would get this:

```
check($paths, 'public/file.php')
//check: /home/user/soloj/public/public/file.php
//check: /home/user/soloj/temppublic/file.php <-- incorrect
```

Instead of:

```
check($paths, 'public/file.php')
//check: /home/user/soloj/public/public/file.php
//check: /home/user/soloj/temp/public/file.php
```